# Color coordinating a sunburst plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, sunburst-diagram

I have a working sunburst plot in r, but would like to have it be color coded. I have labeled the different pieces by letter, and then 0, 1, and 2. I would like to be able to have all of the letters be one color, all of the 0's be one color, and the same for the 1's and 2's.

I have been trying to use the "rects.fill.aes" within sunburst, but I am not sure how to use that in order to get the coloring to work. I will have the coding process I have been using following this paragraph to ensure that you have all of the knowledge necessary. Also, if anyone knows how to have it so the inner node labels say something other then "NoName" I would appreciate that as well for future projects.

```
library(ggsunburst)


nw<-"(A, B, C, D, E, F, ((1)1,(1)1)G, ((2)2,(2)2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)H, ((1)0)AG,((2)0,((1)1)1)I,(((2)2)2)J, K, L, M, ((((1)0)1)1, (((1)0)1)1, (((1)0)1)1,(((2)2)0)2, (((2)2)0)2)N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,(1,1,1)W,X,(2)Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,((((1)1)1)1)AE,((((1)1)1)1)AF);"

sb<- sunburst_data(nw)

sunburst(sb)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I believe that if you download the latest version from github, the NoName problem is solved 
https://github.com/didacs/ggsunburst

You can use `rects.fill.aes` as follows:

```
library(ggsunburst)
nw <-"(A, B, C, D, E, F, ((1)1,(1)1)G, ((2)2,(2)2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)H, ((1)0)AG,((2)0,((1)1)1)I,(((2)2)2)J, K, L, M, ((((1)0)1)1, (((1)0)1)1, (((1)0)1)1,(((2)2)0)2, (((2)2)0)2)N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,(1,1,1)W,X,(2)Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,((((1)1)1)1)AE,((((1)1)1)1)AF);"
sb <- sunburst_data(nw)
```

`sunburst_data` returns a list of data.frames, `sb$rects` is the one you can use for colors

```
> head(sb$rects)
  xmin xmax ymin ymax x name leaf
1  0.5  1.5   -5   -4 1    A TRUE
2  1.5  2.5   -5   -4 2    B TRUE
3  2.5  3.5   -5   -4 3    C TRUE
4  3.5  4.5   -5   -4 4    D TRUE
5  4.5  5.5   -5   -4 5    E TRUE
6  5.5  6.5   -5   -4 6    F TRUE
```

you can use any of those columns to color your sunburst. Because you have NAs in your names, you can assign a specific color to those. Of course you can add additional columns to `sb$rects` if you wish

```
sunburst(sb, rects.fill.aes = "name") + scale_fill_discrete(na.value = "white")
```

[image]